# Why is this printer VBScript running so slow

Tags: visual-studio-2010, printing, vbscript, vb6

This vBscript seems to be taking forever.  What it does is query a print server for  a list of printers based upon the computer name.  For example if the Computer Name is "SLS-201-A001" the printer name may be  "SLS-P201-D

```
'Key vars
printServer = "PRINT_SERVER"

Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

'Extract computer name and take the first two fields
cNameParts=Split(WshNetwork.ComputerName,"-")
printerNamePrefix = cNameParts(0) + "-P" + cNameParts(1)

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & printServer & "\root\cimv2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name LIKE '" + printerNamePrefix + "-%'",,48)

printerName = ""

For Each printerObj in colItems
    printerName = printerObj.Name
Next


PrinterPath = "\\SHARE\" + printerName
MsgBox "Adding " + PrinterPath
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection PrinterPath, PrinterDriver
WshNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter PrinterPath
```

Comment: Is your bottleneck on the `ExecQuery()` call?

Comment: You appear to be only interest in Printers Name, so why not `.ExecQuery("Select Name from Win32_Printer WHERE Name LIKE '" + printerNamePrefix + "-%'",,48)`? Throw in `Wscript.Echo Now & vbTab & "Stage x"` at various locations to determine exactly where it is at slowest. Better to run this with cscript.exe.